# insert primary key of related model - django tastype

Tags: python, json, django, rest, tastypie

I have 2 tables

1. Mobilizer (it contain user details along with mobile no)
2. smsdata(hold data send from particular moblizer)

I need to use json post from sms server .. i am using django tastypie. MY json input will be as below

```
{"Df": 11.0, "Dm": 1.0, "Jf": 1.0, "Jm": 1.0, "Of": 2.0, "Om": 2.0, "Tf": 2.0, "mobile_no": '98xxxxxxxxx'}
```

table structure of smsdata

```
df dm jf jm of om tf mobilizer_id
```

so the problem is **how to resolve mobilizer_id from mobile_no and insert it into smsdata restfully**

so far i tried below

```
from tastypie.resources import ModelResource
from indicators.models import Smsdata,Sfields
from geography.models import mobilizer
from tastypie import fields
from tastypie.authorization import Authorization
from tastypie.authentication import BasicAuthentication

#to override authentication for POST,PUT and DELETE only
class MyCustomAuthentication(BasicAuthentication):
    def is_authenticated(self, request, **kwargs):
        if request.method == 'GET':
            return True
        return super(MyCustomAuthentication,self).is_authenticated(request, **kwargs)

class smsResource(ModelResource):
    #mobilizer = fields.ToManyField('path.to.api.mobilizerResource', attribute='mobilizer', related_name='sms')
    #field = fields.ToManyField('path.to.api.fieldsResource', attribute='field', related_name='sms1')

    class Meta:
        queryset = Smsdata.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'sms-sent'
        authorization = Authorization()
        authentication = MyCustomAuthentication()

class mobilizerResource():
    sms = fields.ToOneField(smsResource, 'sms',related_name='mobilizer')

    class Meta:
        queryset = mobilizer.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'mobilizer'

class fieldsResource():
    sms1 = fields.ToOneField(smsResource, 'sms',related_name='field')

    class Meta:
        queryset = Sfields.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'fields'
```

Comment: Should I supose that you cannot get mobilizer using mobile_no ? something like `Mobilizer.objects.get(mobile_no=mobile_no)` ?

Comment: yes but how to pass that on json post

Comment: What data do you need to pass to json ? Id of the object or object data ? If you need just some specific data of the object you can create a method of the object like `def object_to_json()` where you return the data you need converted to json. In django view you can do `import json` and `json.parse(whatever)` to parse a list or a variable to json

Comment: mobilizer_id.......................